# Unable to hooking UITextfield Class via theos

Tags: uitextfield, uitextview, jailbreak, cydia, tweak

I want to develop simple tweak for hooking uitextfield or uitextview. My have code as below

```
%hook UITextView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame webView:(id)view
{
    UIAlertView *keyAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"testApp" message:@"Test" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [keyAlert show];
    [keyAlert release];

    return %orig;
}
%end
```

its execute successfully but i am unable to get any output. please check this tweak and help me and please suggest me if i am going in any wrong direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you could be doing wrong here:

1) UITextView doesn't necessarily call that method on init; It might be calling 
-initWithFrame: , -initWithFrame:font: or -initWithFrame:webView: (or even just -init, and be setting the frame later on) . You should hook all cases and see if you get any results and on which one of them.

```
%hook UITextView
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    %log; // conveniently NSLogs self,selector,arguments
    return %orig;
}
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame font:(UIFont *)font
{
    %log; 
    return %orig;
}
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame webView:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    %log; 
    return %orig;
}
%end
```

2) Make sure the process you're hooking onto is the one calling the method. If your project's plist filters "com.apple.springboard" and you're testing this into another app, e.g. "com.apple.mobilesafari", it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, If i want to hooking every textview of textfield of iPhone means not only for springboard than how can i do it. and thanks again for your helpful reply.

Comment: and this kind of problem i am already facing for hooking uikeyboard, if its working on only for spring board but in inner app like notes, or in other iOS app its not working

Comment: If you want to hook every UITextView, you should filter "com.apple.UIKit" in your dylib's plist instead.

Comment: thanks a lot its working now.... i have another issue regarding theos tweak can you please look in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911154/replace-keyboard-with-custom-keyboard-for-ios-via-theos-tweak.

Comment: and is it possible to hook the textView delegate method